# Cache Python pip dependencies with CircleCI CLI local

Tags: python, pip, circleci

According to [the CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/#limitations-of-running-jobs-locally):

> Caching is not currently supported in local jobs. When you have either a `save_cache` or `restore_cache` step in your config, circleci will skip them and display a warning.

As far as I can see this makes the `circleci local execute` option much weaker, since I like it for the speed-up in my development cycle it allows.

Some people have developed fairly hectic-looking [custom solutions](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/dependencies-caching-on-local-circleci-builds/25473).

A CircleCI employee suggested a simple-sounding workaround in [this feature request](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/support-cache-in-local-builds/11712) on the topic, but didn't go into enough detail for me to work out how to do this.

So how can I cache `pip install` dependencies in CircleCI when running via the CLI? A solution involving mounting a local directory seems like the simplest.

### My setup

I think the only relevant part of my setup is this:

```yaml
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.8
```